# How to scrape data faster with selenium and django

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-views

I am working on a web scraping project. In this project, I have written the necessary code to scrape the required information from a website using `python` and `selenium`. All of this code resides in multiple methods in a class. This code is saved as ***`scraper.py`***.

When I execute this code, the program takes sometime between **6 and 10 seconds** to extract all the necessary information from the website.

I wanted to create a UI for this project. I used `django` to create the UI. In the webapp, there is a form which when submitted opens a new browser window and starts the scraping process.

I access the ***`scraper.py`*** file in ***`django views`***, where depending on the form inputs, the scraping occurs. While this works fine, the execution is very slow and takes almost **2 minutes** to finish running.

How do I make the execution of the code faster using django faster? can you point me some tutorial on how to convert the ***`scraper.py`*** code into an api that django can access? will this help in making the code faster?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Few tiny tips,

- How is your scraper.py working in the first place? Does it simply print the site links/details, or store it in a text file, or return them? What exactly happens in it?
- If you wish to use your scraper.py as an "API" write your scraper.py code within a function that returns the details of your scraped site as a dictionary. Django's views.py can easily handle such dictionaries and send it over to your frontend HTML to replace the parts written in Jinja2.
- Further speed can be achieved (in case your scraper does larger jobs) by using multi-threading and/or multi-processing. Do explore both :)